# Including an update query into my login script for adding login IP address?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to include this update function to my login script, so everytime the user login .. it will update the login ip address.

and this is the full login function: (**my question is where exactly in this script below I can implement the above update line, so it will be correct without screwing something ?)**

Comment: just put it inside the second if block

Comment: Directly after `$user = $user->row();` line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function login_do()
{
    if ( $_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] )
    {
        $user = $this->db->where( array( 'users_name' => trim( $_POST['username'] ), 'users_password' => sha1( md5( $_POST['password'] ) ) ) )->get( 'users' );
        if ( $user->num_rows == '1' )
        {
            $user = $user->row();
            $data = array( 'logged' => true, 'users_id' => $user->users_id );

            //HERE
            $this->db->update( 'users', array( 'users_login_ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ), array( 'users_id' => $user->users_id ) );

            //REST OF CODE ...
```